# Import list of users - check enabled / disabled - Export list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way I can import a list of users by their Full name (DisplayName), check if their account is enabled/disabled and export the list with the data.

```
Import-csv "C:\userList.csv" | 
    Get-ADUser -Filter {$_.name } | 
    Select name, enabled |  
    Export-csv -path C:\accStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Assuming my import list has a column 'name' and a full name in the below cells.

Comment: We don't add "solved" to titles here. If you fixed your issue, post the fix as an **answer**, and then mark the answer accepted.

Comment: Hi Joel, I didn't set it so I could answer it myself. Hence the question.

Comment: You can always add an answer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed this issue:

```
Import-Csv "C:\userlist.csv" |
    %{  Get-AdUser -filter "name -eq '$($_.username)'" } | 
    Select Name, enabled | 
    Export-csv -path C:\accStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```